# The easiest way of using customized hyphenation patterns in xelatex+polyglossia

Tags: xetex, hyphenation, format-files

I would like to use xelatex+polyglossia with my own hyphenation patterns. I managed to load the patterns by adding a line

`yhgreek yhpatterns.tex`

to

`/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat`

(which was quite hard to find since the `language.dat` file is opened by an `\openin` command which leaves no trace in the log file) and so I got an 86th language stored. I guess that by using `\language85` I will be able to use the patterns.

But this number may change from one TeXlive version to another. Is there some better way to use the patterns independently of their order in the `language.dat` file, for example via the name `yhgreek` which is the first argument on the line? If it exists, a command such as

`\usehyphenationpatterns{yhgreek}`

would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Imho the language.dat in texmf-var is autogenerated.  As the comments in the files suggest, use a own language-local.dat in `TEXMFLOCAL/tex/generic/config/language-local.dat`.  Normally you should be able to use your language with `\makeatletter \language\l@yhgreek`. Or with \selectlanguage{yhgreek}: polyglossia will complain about the missing gloss-file but try to load the patterns.

Comment: why polyglossia and not babel? (the latter is more actively maintained these days)